# Show $(a_{1_n}, a_{2_n}, \ldots, a_{k_n}) \to (a_1, a_2, \ldots a_k) $ if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{j_n} = a_j$ for $1 \le j \le k$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

For any $j$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $N_j$ s.t. $n \ge N_j \implies |a_{j_n} - a_j| < \epsilon.$ If we let $\epsilon = \sqrt k$, then $k \ge 1 \iff \sqrt k \ge 1 \iff |a_{j_n} - a_j| < 1$. Then if $N = \max\{N_i\}_{i=1}^k$, we have for any $n \ge N$, $$|(a_{1_n}, a_{2_n}, \ldots, a_{k_n}) - (a_1, a_2, \ldots a_k)|  \\ = \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k|a_{j_n} - a_j|^2} \\ < \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k(1)^2} \\ = \sqrt k = \epsilon$$

To me this looks like it works. But we want the inequality above to hold for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, yet I defined $\epsilon:= \sqrt k.$ If the proof above is not correct, how can I fix it? Thanks.

EDIT:

Following @Alan's answer below, the proof above is fixed as follows:

For any $j$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $N_j$ s.t. $n \ge N_j \implies |a_{j_n} - a_j| < \epsilon.$ Then if $N = \max\{N_i\}_{i=1}^k$, we have for any $n \ge N$, $$|(a_{1_n}, a_{2_n}, \ldots, a_{k_n}) - (a_1, a_2, \ldots a_k)|  \\ = \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k|a_{j_n} - a_j|^2} \\ < \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt k}\right)^2} \\ = \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{\epsilon^2}{k}}  = \epsilon$$

edit:

What's up with the downvote, though? We are not allowed to make mistakes on this site? If I knew the proof, I wouldn't have come here. LOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon >0$, there exist naturals $N_1, N_2\cdots, N_n$ such that for each $j\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$,
$$|a_{j_n} - a_j| < \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{k}}\: \: \forall\: n\geqslant N_{j}.$$
Now, it immediately follows that
$$\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k|a_{j_n} - a_j|^2}<\varepsilon\:\: \forall \:n\geqslant \underset{j}{\max}N_j.$$
The proof is complete.